What's the subject of the "tipped"
Consider this passage from Smiley’s People (John Le Carré, 1990):

On top of the food-store lay a parcel of Gauloises Caporal cigarettes, Vladimir’s favourites when he couldn’t get his Russians. Tipped, he noticed, reading the different legends.

What’s the subject of this “tipped”? Is it “he”? So it can also be put as “he tipped, he noticed”?

Isn't a filter cigarette a tipped one? The Gouloises were tipped, he noticed as he was reading wording on the parcel.

It might have said filtre.  Maybe the author is making it up.

The subject is the cigarettes, through simple pragmatics. The only preceding noun that can be described as  "tipped" is the cigarettes.

You need to attribute your quote: John le Carré; Smiley's People.

@Xanne It does. The passage continues: "Duty Free." Filtre." Marked "Exportation" and "Made in France."

There lay a parcel of Gauloises Caporal cigarettes. [The cigarettes were] tipped, he noticed . . .

tipped adj1
4. = filter-tipped adj. Also absol., filter-tipped cigarettes. 1964– Source: Oxford English
Dictionary (login required)


What is being noticed here? I don't see how the phrase he noticed stands in relation to the rest of the sentence.

“He noticed* is part of character development.

What is being noticed? The fact that the cigarettes were tipped.

@user405662 The two sentences should be read in context

@DjinTonic Could you please parse it?

@user405662 Tinfoil Hat has done that in his answer: [The cigarettes were] tipped, he [Smiley] noticed.

Is it slightly unusually put or does it appear so to me only? Smiley? You mean Vladimir?

@user405662 Nothing unusual, just economically put: le Carré is a subtle writer.

@user405662 The context leading up to this is needed to know who is doing the noticing. Maybe Smiley is noticing something about Vladimir's possessions.
